# Can't make Ajax links right-clickable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, onclick, hyperlink

I am having a problem, my website www.projectbuilder.tk is 100% ajax powered, how I have ran into a problem that seems to stump me, I can set the urlbar/history to each visited page, and have php loading the pages on the user's first visit based on ?page= from there all pages and data is loaded via ajax.

The problem is that no one can actually right click the links (as I cannot give them the href attribute without causing the page to reload, and skipping the onclick event)

So my question is how do I make the ajax links look like normal links for right-click and open in new window, or tab, or copy url? thanks.

Comment: The browser's back button doesn't work either, which is a major problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put the normal link in the 'href' tag, but adjust your onclick jquery handler method to this:

```
function handleLinkClick(event){
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    ... Continue as normal ...
}
```

The 'preventDefault' stops the normla event propogation so left clicking the link will use your onclick method without sacrificing the valuable info stored in the HREF. Also. Take caution of using jqueries 'live' binding. It used to capture right-clicks as well, may not be the case any more though.

Sorry just realized i assumed you were using jquery. Just returning false, as the other poster mentioned should work fine. I'm so used to jQuery these days.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean, all I want to do is disable the links from working so my ajax can load it, and that code you've written doesn't work(because I don't understand how to implement it, yes my site used jquery, but my friend has written all the jquery code. I added this code to the top of my page, and the links still refreshed the page when clicked.

Comment: If you are trying to stop the default behavior of a link, then your site is likely using javascript to do it. I'm just indicating that wherever the method is that is handling the onclick of your links, needs to indicate that the default click event should not continue, which will stop the default behavior of the link and rely soley on your js method. With that in place then you can add the normal link data to your ahref, which should allow right clicks to works as normal. That help?

Comment: You don't normally need the `if(event)` presumably that function is always called from an event. Only do it as an `if` if you know that function might be called in other ways.

Comment: True, I'm just in the habit of doing it that way so I always have the option to call the method without an event.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you give them href without skipping the onclick?

Just return false from the onclick handler and it won't use the href.

Am I missing something? Because this is very basic.

Comment: The only thing I know how to do in javascript is basic coding, and ajax, I've never had a reason to learn javascript, so I don't entirely understand it.

Comment: I have placed 'return false;' at the end of my ajax function, and it still reloads the page because of the href.

Comment: var PBID = getCookie("PBID");
var PBPASS = getCookie('PBPASS');

xmlhttp.open("GET","fetch.php?ID="+page+"&cmd=page&buffer=1&PBID="+PBID+"&PBPASS="+PBPASS,true);
xmlhttp.send();
return false;

Comment: The return false goes in the onClick, not the function. `A href="..." onClick="call_function(); return false;">` alternative: `A href="..." onClick="return call_function();">` then return false from the function. (I'm assuming you are defining the `onClick` in html, but that's not the only way to do it.)

Comment: ohhhh I see now, that was so simple it escaped my mind, thank you so much!

Comment: @ZachLitzinger If the answer is good, click the arrow near it to accept it.